# How to save the status of a cell so when I scroll or leave the page it doesn't refresh the cells?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to make a store for a game where you can buy different colors of balls. I'm using a UICollectionView with all white balls to begin with, when I click a cell, it changes the white ball image to a colored ball image (EDIT: an image from a pre made array of colored images). when I scroll down and scroll back up, the cells I selected are reset to the white ball image. I don't want this obviously.

I've tried using the method already built into the UICollectionView class with didSelectItemAt but when I scroll down and back up it gets all messed up (When i select a cell a different one's image is changed not the correct one). I've tried using isSelected in the collectionViewCell class but I can't get the indexpath in here so I can't save which cells are selected.

```
override var isSelected: Bool{
    didSet{
        if self.isSelected
        {
            textImage.image = images[indexPath.item]    // I don't know what to put here I don't have the indexPath

        }
        else
        {
            textImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "circleWhite")

        }
    }
}
```

Any help is great, I am fairly new to coding in Xcode so some explanation of what to do here is very much appreciated.

EDIT: I have an array of images that should be the store, not just one different color, multiple colors. When I click on a cell, it should access the image in the corresponding index in the array and use that image to replace the white circle.

Comment: You could adjust the underlying array and redraw it as needed.

Comment: jessi- that's what I'm trying to do but I can't adjust the array without knowing what indexPath I clicked on. I am adjusting the array in my UICollectionView class, but when in the UICollectionViewCell class I can't access the specific array index without the indexPAth

Comment: can you use `didselectItemAtPath` (which will give you the index of selected) and perhaps you can do something with that index value (store it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did the same thing in our code.Below is the solution for this.

1.Take an array of tuple to maintain selected status and specific colors or what ever you want.

```
var arrColor = [(isSelected:Bool,color:UIColor)]()
```

2. Now do the below code on cellForItemAt.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    guard let collectionViewCell = self.iconCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? EditDeviceCollectionViewCell else { return UICollectionViewCell() }

    if arrColor[indexPath.item].isSelected{
        arrColor[indexPath.item].color = .white
    }else {
        arrColor[indexPath.item].color = .black
    }

    return  collectionViewCell
}
```

3.Now write the data source method and use below for color

```
//MARK:- UICollectionViewDelegate
```

extension yourViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    arrColor[indexPath.item].isSelected = true

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    arrColor[indexPath.item].isSelected = false.
}
```

}

Happy Coding

Comment: I edited my question to provide a little more clarification. I don't want it to just change to orange, I want it to change to a specific color in an array. Once I can do that then I can just access that spot in the array when remaking the cell when it is scrolled. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the help!! I ended up doing it a slightly different way but the information you provided definitely helped!

Answer (score 0):

When you scroll off the screen the cells get prepareForReuse called on them. What you need to do is store the state of the color somewhere else - like on the collectionView or a viewModel. And when cellForRow is called you pull the color to show for that row from the saved state variable.

Essentially what’s happening is the cells are being reused when they go off screen to save memory. So when you scroll back to them they are re-created often with the state of another cell since cells are reused.

Comment: I'm trying to store the state of the color somewhere else, however at first all are white. Then once on is clicked it changes to a different image, a color. With the way I am doing it now, I have a method to see if the cell is pressed in the UICollectionViewCell class, and when I register the click here I can't access the index path of the cell that was clicked. So when the cells are re made I can't tell the code which cell to make a certain color since I don't know the index path. Does this make sense? Or am I doing wrong...